# Is riding Roach actually faster than running?

Tags: the-witcher-3

Sometimes I ride Roach to cross an area where I have easily done so on foot, but Roach has trouble doing it.

I haven't seen much difference between running and riding Roach. Is Roach actually faster?

Comment: Traveling on Roach is faster anywhere but in Skellige. If you have not progressed that far, you will find out why at a later point.

Comment: Roach totally hauls ...!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Yes, Roach is *much* faster, generally speaking. There are a few advantages to running, mainly that you can go through water, while Roach may or may not be able to.

However, Roach doesn't take fall damage, so you can jump from cliffs while on Roach and not die. Another advantage to using Roach is that you can auto-run along paths and not worry about straying.

Comment: You also have the choice to "galopp" for a specific time. Then you are much faster then running.

Answer (score 4):

Roach is faster especially when galloping. Buy, win or find better saddles to increase Roach's stamina so she can gallop longer.

If you have the 'Blood and Wine' DLC you can also get a boost to Roach's stamina by upgrading the stables at Corvo Bianco.

When on foot you can use the Werewolf decoction to be able to run indefinitely.

Comment: You can also auto gallop on paths for free